# Is there an O(1) method to choose between n branches in C, like with an array of function pointers or array of goto labels?

Tags: arrays, c

I'm working on a calculator, and at the part where operations are actually executed, I have a big long switch block that looks something like this (the cases go up linearly starting at 1):

```
switch(operator) {
   case 1:
      a = a + b;
      break;
   case 2:
      a = a - b;
      break;
   ...
   case 20:
      a = sin(a);
      break;
```

I have quite a few operators and functions at this point and testing each case one at a time doesn't seem like it would be the fastest option.

Is there a way to use a table (such as an array of goto labels, or an array of function pointers) so that the "operator" variable would cause the program to jump to the appropriate operation without the program having to test for each of the cases?  If so, how would I go about doing this, given the above code?

Comment: This *is* the O(1) method, with typical compiler behavior.

Comment: Get it working, then profile and worry about optimizations.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica So a compiler will internally use a table like the one I'm describing?

Comment: With a "dense" set of cases like this, yes. With less dense cases, it might use a decision tree or something else. (Also I hope you remembered your `break`s in your real code.)

Comment: This is where having an `enum` to enumerate your operations and give them meaningful labels goes a long way. You could easily botch something here and mess up an implementation where you meant `23` but put `22` twice. With an enum you'd have clear labels like `OP_ADD`, `OP_SUBTRACT`, etc.

Comment: Any decent C compiler will take the density of case values into account, and if sufficiently dense, it will generate a dispatch table.  Leave it to the compiler to optimize.  If sparse, it may use an optimized hash function, or at worst do a binary search which would be O(log(n)).

Comment: @tadman Yeah I'm using enums, i just used literals in this example to emphasize the fact  that each of the cases are consecutive

Comment: The compiler doesn't really care if they're consecutive so much as what the numerical range is, and how many branches there are.

Comment: The best time to optimize is never (i.e. if you don’t have a problem you don’t have to optimize). The second-best time to optimize is when you have an actual performance problem. The WORST time to “optimize” is at design time. To quote Donald Knuth: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil".  And while we're quoting - to quote Kent Beck, "Make it run.  Make it run right.  Make it run right fast". Optimization is literally the *last* thing you should be doing, because until you're done you don't know where the problems are. You're guessing - how good are you at guessing games?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threaded_code might be of interest.

Answer (score 0):

It can not be faster then switch and I will show you why. Here is my version of your function with switch

```c
void switch_fun(int operator) {
    switch(operator) {
        case 0:
            a = a + b;
        break;
        case 1:
            a = a - b;
        break;
        case 2:
            a = a * b;
        break;
    }
}
```

Which translate to this assembler (with comments for non-assembly people)

```
switch_fun:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], edi ## copy 'operator'
        cmp     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 2 ## compare 'operator' with 2
        je      .L2 ## if 'operator' is equal to 2 jump to .L2 (few lines below)
        cmp     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 0 ## same comparition for 0
        je      .L4
        cmp     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 1 ## and for 1
        je      .L5
        jmp     .L6 ## if nothing match jump at the end of the function
.L4:
        mov     edx, DWORD PTR a[rip]
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR b[rip]
        add     eax, edx ## addition, like in case 0:
        mov     DWORD PTR a[rip], eax
        jmp     .L3 ## jump at the end
.L5:
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR a[rip]
        mov     edx, DWORD PTR b[rip]
        sub     eax, edx ## subtraction
        mov     DWORD PTR a[rip], eax
        jmp     .L3
.L2:
        mov     edx, DWORD PTR a[rip]
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR b[rip]
        imul    eax, edx ## multiplication
        mov     DWORD PTR a[rip], eax
        nop
.L3:
.L6:
        nop
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

It's pretty simple construction and probably impossible to optimize even more, but let's try. Here I have version of this function but with array of addresses to goto labels.

```c
void array_fun(int operator) {
    void* labels[] = {&&addition, &&subtraction, &&mul};
    
    goto *labels[operator];

    addition:
    a = a + b;
    goto outer;
    subtraction:
    a = a - b;
    goto outer;
    mul:
    a = a * b;
    outer:
    return;
}
```

Ignoring fact that this code is really unsafe because if operator will be greater then 2 this will crash program but whatever, let's see how this look in assembly.

```
array_fun:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-36], edi
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-32], OFFSET FLAT:.L8
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-24], OFFSET FLAT:.L9
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-16], OFFSET FLAT:.L10 ## here you eliminated some comparitions
    ## but add some new 'moves' and calculations, everything below is practically the same like in first function, it's definitely not faster, probably slower then switch
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-36]
        cdqe
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-32+rax*8]
        nop
        jmp     rax
.L8:
        mov     edx, DWORD PTR a[rip]
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR b[rip]
        add     eax, edx
        mov     DWORD PTR a[rip], eax
        jmp     .L12
.L9:
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR a[rip]
        mov     edx, DWORD PTR b[rip]
        sub     eax, edx
        mov     DWORD PTR a[rip], eax
        jmp     .L12
.L10:
        mov     edx, DWORD PTR a[rip]
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR b[rip]
        imul    eax, edx
        mov     DWORD PTR a[rip], eax
.L12:
        nop
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

**TL;DR** don't try to optimize switch on integers because it's impossible to do
**EDIT:** With array of pointers to functions it would be even worse because you will get overhead because of calling a function

Comment: Add more cases to your switch, enable full optimization, include the proper range checking in your `array_fun` version, then compare. Also, the indirect goto that you use is not standard but supported on some platforms as a compiler extension.

Comment: The ocaml bytecode interpreter has some macro magic to use switch or jumping to labels with the same code depending on compiler support for the latter. It's possible to get pretty creative.